# In Facebook graph API Call Cross browser call not supported in IE(all versions) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?

    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN`    i developed an facebook application, since the offline_access removed i just turned to use the above code
   it works great in FF,Chrome but not IE all versions. when i place the code in  browser address bar it returns the expected result when i try to call through my website it returns

**{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"Error: Access is denied.\r\n"}** 
 IE doesn't support cross browser request what should i do to work in IE please help some one 
i tried " $.support.cors = true;" but no changes , please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a space right before client_secret.

Comment: Anna in the actual request there was no space,though it has the space right before client_secret it will fetch the results. this is not an answer which i expected.

Comment: IE has issues with launching from an iFrame, it's "cross-scripting" protection. So it might have to do with where you're launching it from. It has to be from where you're originating the call, or pass a redirect_url to the other machine. Cross-scripting prevention can also be solved - with various server settings and essentially changing some header info.

Comment: also, a lot of things in FB work better with the right html header: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">"